# Option to not select text when undoing a deletion?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm new to Mac and it seems that on Mac OS Catalina, undoing some text deletion via the keyboard shortcut `command + z` also selects the text that was re-added. For example:

1. Type something
2. Delete the last word using `option + delete`
3. Undo the deletion using `cmd + z`
4. Observe that the last word is selected

This is a little annoying, as I need to explicitly unselect the text before typing again, otherwise I overwrite the text I was trying to add back.

Is there a way to make it so `command + z` does not select the text it adds back?

Comment: I'm not seeing this as something new to Catalina, as I recall it's always been so. Just tested, Windows does it too.

Comment: @Tetsujin fwiw, the address bar in Firefox has a different behaviour from the rest of macOS, and actually aligns with what the asker wants (but only when deleting a single word at the end).

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right! I just tested more thoroughly on Windows and it seems to be a per-app thing, not OS. It just turns out most of the programs I use on Windows did not behave like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tetsujin pointed out, it turns out this is a per-application behavior, not an OS behavior. The same happens in some programs on Windows, and some apps on Mac do not behave like this. Seems like nothing can be done about it.